# Android can't understand and make a SmsReceiver for KitKat devices

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver, android-4.4-kitkat

I followed the Video of DevBytes - Android 4.4 SMS API's - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mdq0R2WQssQ

With no luck i couldn't write a successful app that can receive SMS messages for kitkat devices.

I made the exact format that the DevBytes developer did in his video and when i sent a message in the DDMS + Debug my receiver class Didn't jumped to the Breakpoint.

Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity android:name="com.example.kitkatreceiver.DefaultAppDeliver">
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

        <data android:scheme="sms" />
        <data android:scheme="smsto" />
        <data android:scheme="mms" />
        <data android:scheme="mmsto" />
    </intent-filter>

    </activity>

    <receiver android:name="com.example.kitkatreceiver.KitKatSmsReceiver"
              android:enabled="true"
              android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS">
        <intent-filter android:priority="1000">
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_DELIVER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

</application>
```

Receiver:

public class KitKatSmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    for (SmsMessage smsMessage : Telephony.Sms.Intents.getMessagesFromIntent(arg1)) {
        String messageBody = smsMessage.getMessageBody();
        Log.d("msg", messageBody);
    }

    Bundle b = arg1.getExtras();
    SmsMessage [] msgs;
    if(b != null) {
         Object[] pdus = (Object[]) b.get("pdus");
         msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
         for(int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++){
             msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);
         }
         for(SmsMessage msg : msgs) {

         }
    }
}
```

}

Also i realized that you need to make my app a default app , what if i don't to do that but still catch SMS first instead of the default sms app?

Thanks

Comment: From docs : On Android 4.4, only one app can receive the new SMS_DELIVER_ACTION intent, which the system broadcasts when a new SMS message arrives. Which app receives this broadcast is determined by which app the user has selected as the default SMS app in system settings. So, until you make your app the default app, I dont think you'll be able to 'catch the SMS first'.

Answer (score 0):

Permissions Required :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
```

Also, add the permissions just before the `<application>` tag, not inside the receiver.

Your BroadcastReciever inside the manifest should look like this :

```
<receiver android:name="com.example.kitkatreceiver.KitKatSmsReceiver">  
    <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: Hello Shivam Verma firstly thanks
The permission i already knew , but what u suggested is for API < 4.4 i am looking for the solution that writing a receiver that would accept a SMS message on KitKat device which is used with SMS_DELIVERED

Comment: Also, this'll help you for sure : http://android-developers.blogspot.sg/2013/10/getting-your-sms-apps-ready-for-kitkat.html